# How to i get the count of how many arrays are multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have multidimensional array and i cant work out how to get the count of how many arrays are inside the multidimensional array, count($array) isn't working. The array is below

```
     Array
       (
    [data] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => text
                [fname] => Empty
                [value] => 
                [req] => Yes
                [valType] => None
                [errorMsg] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => tickbox
                [fname] => Empty
                [value] => Empty
                [req] => Yes
                [valType] => None
                [errorMsg] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type] => select
                [fname] => Empty
                [req] => Yes
                [valType] => None
                [optionsList] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => :empty
                    )

                [errorMsg] => 
            )

    )

 )
```

Count is returning 1 but the result im looking for is 3. Any help would be great thanks

Ian

Comment: presumable `$array[0].count` is 3

Comment: count($array['data']) ; ??

Comment: Thanks Robert that worked, cant believe i missed that!!

Comment: @NewAlexandria: In ruby?

Comment: @AbraCadaver oh.   ...meh ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try counting the array in the array: `count($array['data']);`

Comment: Thanks for this all sorted, i will mark solved once im allowed in 10 mins